# Restrict target device to iPhone 4 using ARMV7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, armv7

Does configuring the architecture to ARMV7 restricts the app to be installed only to devices starting from 3Gs/iPhone 4? I'd also like to know if there's another way to enable device version restrictions? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you restrict the application to only support ARMv7 devices via the `armv7` entry in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, that won't stop support at the iPhone 4 level, it will also support the iPhone 3G S and 3rd Generation iPod touch. If you really want to restrict to just the iPhone 4 and newer, you could use the `front-facing-camera` hardware filter, although that would also drop out the original iPad.

A full list of devices and what options they support can be found in the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide, Appendix C: Device Compatibility Matrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1). From that matrix, you can see which devices will be blocked for which combination of required hardware capabilities you specify.

Comment: [Updated link to the device compatibility matrix](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/B_DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH17-SW1).

Comment: @KurtRevis - Thanks, updated with the new link. They keep moving this around.

Comment: "Sorry, that page cannot be found." Seems to have moved again :(

Comment: <a href="https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1"> Updated Link </a>